# Changing the interpolate symbols in Angular breaks ui-select2 with error: $select.getPlaceholder()

Tags: javascript, angularjs, parsing, ui-select2, ui-select

I have an angular application which I've had to change interpolate symbols to '((' instead of '{{' using:

```
app.config(['$interpolateProvider', function($interpolateProvider){
    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('((').endSymbol('))');
}]);
```

This works fine generally across the app however adding the `multiple` attribute in a ui-select throws up an error:

> Error: [$parse:ueoe] Unexpected end of expression:
>   $selectMultiple.getPlaceholder(
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.15/$parse/ueoe?p0=%24selectMultiple.getPlaceholder(
>       at REGEX_STRING_REGEXP (angular.js:63)
>       at Parser.peekToken (angular.js:12077)
>       at Parser.functionCall (angular.js:12377)
>       at Parser.primary (angular.js:12054)
>       at Parser.unary (angular.js:12330)
>       at Parser.multiplicative (angular.js:12313)
>       at Parser.additive (angular.js:12304)
>       at Parser.relational (angular.js:12295)
>       at Parser.equality (angular.js:12286)
>       at Parser.logicalAND (angular.js:12277)

The html code:

```
<ui-select multiple tagging="tagTransform" tagging-label="new tag" ng-model="tagging.selectedTags" theme="bootstrap" ng-disabled="disabled" style="width: 800px;">
    <ui-select-match placeholder="Select tag...">(($item))</ui-select-match>
    <ui-select-choices repeat="tag in tagging.tags | filter: $select.search">
        <div ng-bind-html="((tag | highlight: $select.search))"></div>
    </ui-select-choices>
</ui-select>
```

Removing `multiple` in ui-select works fine.